# git diff between two branches when the path has changed

Tags: git

I need to understand changes to a file between two releases represented by my current master and branch new_branch.  Normally, I would run the following if path/name are the same in both branches.

git diff new_branch -- path/file

What do I do when path/file is different between the two branches?

I can fallback and create another cloned repository and checkout new_branch.  Then do unix's sdiff.  I was just wondering if the authors of git diff anticipated this scenario and built something in to handle it.

--Thank you,
--Mike Jr.

Comment: If the answer does not work for you (like in my case), check https://stackoverflow.com/q/5730460/711006 for additional options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git has no *real* notion of moved/renamed/copied files, however it has heuristics to try and detect those cases and then display them in a nice way.

That said, you can instruct `git-diff` to use those heuristics to detect renames by passing it the `-M` flag. With that you can try

```
git diff -M new_branch -- new-path/file old-path/file
```

and see if it works in your specific case. Further, `git diff -M --stat new_branch` will give you an overview of the changes, and also show you what renames Git's heuristics picked up.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a champ.  I wish the git-diff man page had included your example.